# Error installing tex-common on 16.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, dpkg

Attempting to install tex-common on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install tex-common
```

Fails, with `/usr/sbin/update-updmap: line 235: bin/mkdir: No such file or directory`

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                    
Building dependency tree                                                                                                                                                         
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                
The following NEW packages will be installed:                                                                                                                                    
tex-common                                                                                                                                                                       
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.                                                                                                                  
  Need to get 0 B/545 kB of archives.                                                                                                                                            
  After this operation, 851 kB of additional disk space will be used.                                                                                                            
  Selecting previously unselected package tex-common.                                                                                                                            
  (Reading database ... 214063 files and directories currently installed.)                                                                                                       
Preparing to unpack .../tex-common_6.04_all.deb ...                                                                                                                              
  Unpacking tex-common (6.04) ...                                                                                                                                                
  Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...                                                                                                                                   
  Setting up tex-common (6.04) ...                                                                                                                                               
  /usr/sbin/update-updmap: line 235: bin/mkdir: No such file or directory                                                                                                        
dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):                                                                                                                         
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1                                                                                                       
Errors were encountered while processing:                                                                                                                                        
tex-common                                                                                                                                                                       
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestions? Tried some of the suggestions mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512848/tex-common-troubleshooting-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: Try to upgrade first. Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. Then _(maybe after a reboot if needed)_ run `sudo apt install --reinstall tex-common`.

Comment: Still seeing the same errors, and now I'm also seeing errors related to `keyboard-configuration`, `console-setup-linux`, and `console-setup`, which seem to stem from `bin/setupcon: 806: bin/setupcon: bin/../bin/ckbcomp: not found`.

Answer (score 5):

Same situation for me, solved with these steps:

```
sudo apt remove --purge tex-common '^texlive'
sudo rm -rf /etc/texmf/
sudo apt install tex-common texlive-base texlive-latex-recommended \
                 texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended latex-cjk-all
```

Comment: this does not help, plus it installs unnecessary language packs. downvote