# Ubuntu apt-get upgrade (or install) always returns error

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

Whenever I try to install/upgrade apt-get will always return an error, and always the same error.

```
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Setting up nautilus (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tipa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Where only the last 3 occur every time.

`whereis tipa` doesn't show any results. And `dpkg -L tipa` shows a lot:

```
/.
/var
/var/lib
/var/lib/tex-common
/var/lib/tex-common/fontmap-cfg
/var/lib/tex-common/fontmap-cfg/texmf
/var/lib/tex-common/fontmap-cfg/texmf/tipa.cfg
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/tipa
/usr/share/doc/tipa/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/tipa/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/tipa/copyright
/usr/share/texmf
/usr/share/texmf/tex
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/tone.sty
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3ptm.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/exaccent.sty
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/ts3cmss.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3phv.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/utipxss.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/ts3phv.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/extraipa.sty
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/uxipx.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/ts3cmtt.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/utipxtt.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/vowel.sty
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/utipx.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/ts3ptm.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/tipa.sty
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmss.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/uxipxss.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmtt.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/ts3enc.def
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/ts3cmr.fd
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/tipx.sty
/usr/share/texmf/fonts
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxbx10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipx9.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipass10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsb10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipass17.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxts10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipx10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipasb10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasi10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipatt10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipatt9.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipabx8.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipab10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipx8.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasb10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxbx12.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxss12.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxtt10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsb10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsl12.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipasl10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxss10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasb10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipass8.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasl12.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipabx10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxsl10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxsi10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsl8.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxbs10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipass10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipats10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipabs10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa17.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxtt12.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipass17.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipatt12.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxbs10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipabx8.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxts10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxtt12.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipatt9.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipass9.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsl10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipass10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsl9.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipatt8.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasl10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxbx8.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipx12.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasl9.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxsl10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipx8.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipabs10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipass12.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxss8.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipabx9.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxss9.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa17.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipasi10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa12.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxss8.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxbx9.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipass12.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxb10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipa10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipatt8.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxbx10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasl10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxtt8.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxsb10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxss17.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxbx8.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsi10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipx10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipass8.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxsi10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxss10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxss17.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxtt10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxb10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipass9.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa8.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxbx9.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxb10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipatt10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipabx12.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxss12.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipa10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipabx9.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsl12.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxss9.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipx9.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa9.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipass10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxbs10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipabs10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxtt9.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa12.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipasb10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsl9.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxb10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipx12.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipasi10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxbx12.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipatt12.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipab10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasl12.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipx17.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasi10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipx10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxtt9.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxbs10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipx10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsl10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipabx10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxss10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxtt8.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipab10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasl8.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasl9.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipasl8.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipabs10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipasl10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipats10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa9.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsi10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipx17.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipxsl8.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipab10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipabx12.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxsb10.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa8.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/xipxss10.afm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxtt8.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipasb10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/gentipx.sh
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipabx9.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipasl10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxtt10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipxss10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipabase.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipxbs10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipx.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipx9.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxbx8.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipasym2.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxsb10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipabx10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipasl8.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxsl12.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipa17.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipatone.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipabx12.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipadiac.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipatt9.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipabs10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxsi10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipatr.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipa10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipasym1.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipxsi10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipass10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxbx10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxsl10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipaprm.def
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tiparoml.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipasl10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipaextr.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/mkxipapk.sh
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipx10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipasl12.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipagerm.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipasb10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxss10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipaprm.def
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipasl9.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxb10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipa9.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipasym4.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxtt9.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxbx12.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipxb10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipasi10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipapnct.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxss12.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipx10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/genxipa.sh
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipatt10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipx17.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipasi10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxtt12.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipa.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipabx8.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipatt12.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/mktipapk.sh
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipabs10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxss8.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipxsl10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipa8.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipanew.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipab10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipass12.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipasc.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/genxipx.sh
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxss17.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipatt8.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipxsb10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipass9.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxsl8.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxss9.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxsl9.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipasym3.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipats10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipa10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipx8.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipass8.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/gentfm.sh
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipab10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/xipass10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxbx9.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxts10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipx12.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/gentipa.sh
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipass17.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipa12.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/fkr/tipa/tipxbs10.mf
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/tipa.map
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipa10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxss17.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxss10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipa8.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipasb10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipa12.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxbx10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxsl9.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipats10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxts10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipx17.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipa17.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipasb10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxbx8.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipx12.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxtt12.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipass10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipx10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipab10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipasl8.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipass10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipabx12.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipass8.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipatt12.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxss12.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipab10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxbx12.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxsl8.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipass12.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxtt9.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipxsb10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxsl12.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipabs10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipatt8.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipatt9.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxtt10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipa10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxsb10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipabx9.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxss8.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxsi10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipasl10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipxsi10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipxbs10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxb10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipatt10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipa9.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipx10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipabs10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipxsl10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipasi10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxss9.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxtt8.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipasl12.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxbx9.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxbs10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipx8.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipxb10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipabx10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipasl10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipabx8.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/xipxss10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipasi10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipass17.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipasl9.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipass9.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipxsl10.tfm
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/fkr/tipa/tipx9.tfm
```

How to fix this?

the log of `sudo apt -f tipa` is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aufs-tools bridge-utils cgroupfs-mount containerd gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0
  golang-docker-credential-helpers libllvm7 libllvm7:i386 libllvm8
  libllvm8:i386 pigz python-backports.ssl-match-hostname
  python-cached-property python-certifi python-chardet python-docker
  python-dockerpty python-dockerpycreds python-docopt python-funcsigs
  python-functools32 python-jsonschema python-mock python-openssl python-pbr
  python-requests python-texttable python-urllib3 python-websocket python-yaml
  runc ubuntu-fan ubuntu-web-launchers
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up tipa (2:1.3-20) ...
Missing head file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/config/language.us.lua: No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/update-language line 139.
dpkg: error processing package tipa (--configure):
 installed tipa package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tipa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt -f install` , as even if it doesn't resolve the issue, it should provide more clues to follow (or commands, eg. `dpkg-reconfigure`.. etc)

Comment: @guiverc I've done that now, only closer point I get is that `texlive` is missing a configuration file(?)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to reinstall [the package with */usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/config/language.us.lua* file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fusr%2Fshare%2Ftexlive%2Ftexmf-dist%2Ftex%2Fgeneric%2Fconfig%2Flanguage.us.lua) with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall texlive-base
```

And then resume package installation with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Well that gave an error that `tex-common` was breaking. Trying to reinstall `tex-common` gave even more cryptic error message that `E: Internal Error, No file name for tex-common:amd64`. After some time googling I came upon this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/882381/error-installing-tex-common-on-16-04-lts . I followed the steps in the *answer*, no the comments. Which seemed to be the nuclear option of first blasting everything away and then installing it anew.. This seems to work so far (still a bit afraid I "forgot" to install an obscure dependency that was purged)...