# tex-common exit code 1

Tags: updates

Well I tried doing some searching and came up with this site...
[Error installing tex-common on 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882381/error-installing-tex-common-on-16-04-lts)

But it looks like that'll break my system.

Here's what's going on, I'm trying to do updates and when I try to apt-get upgrade it looks like there's a update for tex-common....

```
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up tex-common (6.16) ...
find: ‘/etc/texmf/texmf.d’: No such file or directory
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Building format(s) --all.
    This may take some time...
```

This update ends in....

```
dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 installed tex-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-japanese:
 latex-cjk-japanese depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-japanese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese:
 latex-cjk-chinese depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-chinese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp:
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-common:
 latex-cjk-common depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-cjk:
 texlive-lang-cjk depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-cjk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-japanese:
 texlive-lang-japanese depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-lang-japanese depends on texlive-lang-cjk (>= 2020.20200417); however:
  Package texlive-lang-cjk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-japanese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab:
 latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-korean:
 latex-cjk-korean depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.4+git20170127-3); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-korean depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-korean (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp:
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-korean:
 texlive-lang-korean depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-lang-korean depends on texlive-lang-cjk (>= 2020.20200417); however:
  Package texlive-lang-cjk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-korean (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp:
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp:
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-thai:
 latex-cjk-thai depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.4+git20170127-3); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-thai (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-font-utils:
 texlive-font-utils depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-font-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-other:
 texlive-lang-other depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-other (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-all:
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.4+git20170127-3); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-chinese (>= 4.8.4+git20170127-3); however:
  Package latex-cjk-chinese is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-japanese (>= 4.8.4+git20170127-3); however:
  Package latex-cjk-japanese is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-korean (= 4.8.4+git20170127-3); however:
  Package latex-cjk-korean is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-thai (= 4.8.4+git20170127-3); however:
  Package latex-cjk-thai is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp; however:
  Package latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp; however:
  Package latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp; however:
  Package latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp; however:
  Package latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab; however:
  Package latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-chinese:
 texlive-lang-chinese depends on tex-common (>= 6.13); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-lang-chinese depends on texlive-lang-cjk (>= 2020.20200417); however:
  Package texlive-lang-cjk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-chinese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 latex-cjk-japanese
 latex-cjk-chinese
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp
 latex-cjk-common
 texlive-lang-cjk
 texlive-lang-japanese
 latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab
 latex-cjk-korean
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp
 texlive-lang-korean
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp
 latex-cjk-thai
 texlive-font-utils
 texlive-lang-other
 latex-cjk-all
 texlive-lang-chinese
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

sudo apt remove --purge tex-common '^texlive'
Results with.....

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'texlive-htmlxml' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-pictures' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-metapost-doc' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-portuguese' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-binaries' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-spanish' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-european' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-greek' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-cyrillic' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-font-utils' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-humanities' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-korean' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-music' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-plain-generic' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-latex-recommended-doc' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-fonts-recommended-doc' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-games' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-polish' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-science-doc' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-italian' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-common' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-latex-base' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-bibtex-extra' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-czechslovak' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-all' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-cjk' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-fonts-extra-links' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-pictures-doc' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-latex-base-doc' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-publishers' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-latex-extra-doc' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-chinese' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-formats-extra' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-pstricks-doc' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-math-extra' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-english' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-full' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-humanities-doc' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-latex3' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-base-bin' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-xetex' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-science' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-arabic' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-other' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-base' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-metapost' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-fonts-extra' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-french' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-context' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-german' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-extra-utils' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-latex-extra' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-fonts-extra-doc' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-fonts-recommended' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-publishers-doc' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-arab' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-lang-japanese' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-latex-recommended' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-pstricks' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-luatex' for regex '^texlive'
Note, selecting 'texlive-binaries' instead of 'texlive-base-bin'
Note, selecting 'context' instead of 'texlive-context'
Package 'texlive-latex3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-math-extra' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-arab' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-htmlxml' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-fonts-extra' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-fonts-extra-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-fonts-extra-links' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-fonts-recommended-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-full' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-games' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-humanities' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-humanities-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-all' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-arabic' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-cyrillic' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-czechslovak' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-english' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-european' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-french' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-german' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-italian' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-polish' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-portuguese' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-lang-spanish' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-latex-base-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-latex-extra-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-latex-recommended-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-metapost' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-metapost-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-music' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-pictures-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-pstricks' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-pstricks-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-publishers' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-publishers-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'texlive-science-doc' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dblatex-doc dvisvgm fonts-arphic-bkai00mp fonts-arphic-bsmi00lp fonts-arphic-gbsn00lp fonts-arphic-gkai00mp
  fonts-baekmuk fonts-gfs-baskerville fonts-gfs-porson fonts-lmodern fonts-sil-padauk fonts-tlwg-garuda
  fonts-tlwg-garuda-otf fonts-tlwg-kinnari fonts-tlwg-kinnari-otf fonts-tlwg-laksaman fonts-tlwg-laksaman-otf
  fonts-tlwg-loma fonts-tlwg-loma-otf fonts-tlwg-mono fonts-tlwg-mono-otf fonts-tlwg-norasi fonts-tlwg-norasi-otf
  fonts-tlwg-purisa fonts-tlwg-purisa-otf fonts-tlwg-sawasdee fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-otf fonts-tlwg-typewriter
  fonts-tlwg-typewriter-otf fonts-tlwg-typist fonts-tlwg-typist-otf fonts-tlwg-typo fonts-tlwg-typo-otf
  fonts-tlwg-umpush fonts-tlwg-umpush-otf fonts-tlwg-waree fonts-tlwg-waree-otf fonts-unfonts-core
  fonts-unfonts-extra libalgorithm-c3-perl libapache-pom-java libb-hooks-endofscope-perl libb-hooks-op-check-perl
  libclass-c3-perl libclass-c3-xs-perl libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl
  libclass-xsaccessor-perl libcommons-logging-java libcommons-parent-java libdata-optlist-perl
  libdevel-callchecker-perl libdevel-caller-perl libdevel-globaldestruction-perl libdevel-lexalias-perl
  libdevel-stacktrace-perl libdist-checkconflicts-perl libdynaloader-functions-perl libemail-date-format-perl
  libeval-closure-perl libexception-class-perl libfile-homedir-perl libfile-which-perl libfontbox-java
  libipc-shareable-perl libkpathsea6 liblog-dispatch-perl liblog-log4perl-perl libmail-sendmail-perl
  libmime-charset-perl libmime-lite-perl libmime-types-perl libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl
  libmro-compat-perl libnamespace-autoclean-perl libnamespace-clean-perl libpackage-stash-perl
  libpackage-stash-xs-perl libpadwalker-perl libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl
  libparams-validationcompiler-perl libpdfbox-java libptexenc1 libreadonly-perl libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl
  librole-tiny-perl libsgmls-perl libsombok3 libspecio-perl libsub-exporter-perl libsub-exporter-progressive-perl
  libsub-identify-perl libsub-install-perl libsub-quote-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl libteckit0 libtexlua53
  libtexluajit2 libtext-unidecode-perl libunicode-linebreak-perl libvariable-magic-perl libxstring-perl
  libyaml-tiny-perl libzzip-0-13 ps2eps sgmlspl t1utils tcl teckit tk xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  asciidoc-dblatex* dblatex* docbook-utils* latex-cjk-all* latex-cjk-chinese* latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp*
  latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp* latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp* latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp*
  latex-cjk-common* latex-cjk-japanese* latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab* latex-cjk-korean* latex-cjk-thai* lmodern*
  preview-latex-style* tex-common* tex-gyre* texinfo* texlive* texlive-base* texlive-bibtex-extra* texlive-binaries*
  texlive-extra-utils* texlive-font-utils* texlive-fonts-recommended* texlive-formats-extra* texlive-lang-chinese*
  texlive-lang-cjk* texlive-lang-greek* texlive-lang-japanese* texlive-lang-korean* texlive-lang-other*
  texlive-latex-base* texlive-latex-extra* texlive-latex-recommended* texlive-luatex* texlive-pictures*
  texlive-plain-generic* texlive-science* texlive-xetex* tipa*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 42 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,821 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

I don't want to break my system trying to do a update.
Any suggestions on how to accomplish this without breaking the whole system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet) and [Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056780/) and [Dependency errors prevent all APT commands from running, "Package libappstream-glib8:amd64 is not configured yet"](https://askubuntu.com/q/855359/)

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; a quick scan & most *supported* releases of Ubuntu meet the requirements of your paste, so what are you actually running?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm not used to this forum layout and wasn't even sure these "comments" were replies.
I tried the posted thread "fixes", none worked for me, same error.

My OS is the upgrade to Bullseye on Raspberry Pi.
I got the error shortly following what looked like a successful upgrade.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Bullseye is a character from Toy Story; Ubuntu doesn't use toy story character names; Debian does*