# Problem with installing texlive 2017 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, latex, texlive

I tried to update from texlive 2015 to 2017.

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2017
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

After running the last line, I get a lot of package names with unmet dependencies and the following error:

```
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

But running 
`sudo apt-get -f install` results in another error

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 880678 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2017.20170619-1~16.04.york0_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-fonts-extra-doc (2017.20170619-1~16.04.york0) over (2015.20160320-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2017.20170619-1~16.04.york0_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/mweights/README', which is also in package texlive-latex-extra-doc 2015.20160320-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2017.20170619-1~16.04.york0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It looks like I am stuck with a circular problem.
I tried the solution listed in [Install texlive 2017 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927346/install-texlive-2017-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/928351#928351?newreg=db7528185b6d4a13b23d0102425f44af) but was not successful.

*Can someone help me out please?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually it is not recommeded, but you can force file overwrite with

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2017.20170619-1~16.04.york0_all.deb
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you very much @N0rbert! I had to use the `sudo dpkg -i ...` command and `sudu apt-get install -f ` iteratively until all the packages were unpacked and installed. Finally I ran
 `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.
 Now I have texlive 2017 running on Ubuntu 16.04 without a problem.

Comment: Great! So you can [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) my answer :)

Comment: Sorry. I'm a newbie to this forum. Looks like I accepted it now.

Comment: If individual packages gets pesky, maybe try `sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-*` and finally, try this https://askubuntu.com/a/654680/63298